# how to open panel in % left using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am opening the left panel "300px" ,But I need to open the left panel  80% of the width . can you please tell me how to how left panel not in px in % .

I want to open panel around 80% of width.

http://jsfiddle.net/eHded/4/

```
.panel {
    width:300px;
    float:left;
    height:550px;
    background:#d9dada;
    position:relative;
    left:-300px;

}
.slider-arrow {
    padding:5px;
    width:10px;
    float:left;
    background:#d9dada;
    font:400 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
    left:-300px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/eHded/1675/ use `80%`, simple? Also note that this isn't related to jQM since you're not using jQM.

Comment: ">>" image gone some where else .how to close that panel ..please check open the panel and image gone somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/eHded/1676/

CSS:

```
.panel {
    width:80%;
    left:-80%;

}
.slider-arrow {
    left:-80%;
}
```

And the JS:

```
$('.slider-arrow').click(function(){
    var newWidth = $(this).parent().width() * 0.8;

    if($(this).hasClass('show')){        
    $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({            
      left: "+=" + String(newWidth)
      }, 700, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
      $(this).html('&laquo;').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    }
    else {      
    $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
      left: "-=" + String(newWidth)
      }, 700, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
      $(this).html('&raquo;').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');    
    }
});
```

You find the `parent()` width, get 80% of that, and use that in your animations instead of a set `px` amount.

Comment: ">>" image gone some where else .how to close that panel,there is no such

Comment: @SajadLfc Seems we were working on it at the same time, though nobody copied your answer. If you look they are different.

Comment: any suggestion of this question why ">>" hide when it open left panel

Comment: @user2484319 Not sure what you're seeing but the JSFiddle in my answer does not hide the >> button when opened. What browser are you using?

Comment: i saw it is not hidding but it change it position scrollbar dispay at bottom

Answer (score 1):

try

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7a72x/)

**CSS**

```
.panel {
    width:80%;
    float:left;
    height:550px;
    background:#d9dada;
    position:relative;
    left:-80%;

}
.slider-arrow {
    padding:5px;
    width:10px;
    float:left;
    background:#d9dada;
    font:400 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
    left:-80%;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
    $('.slider-arrow').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('show')){
        $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
          left: "+=80%"
          }, 700, function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });
          $(this).html('&laquo;').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
        }
        else {      
        $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
          left: "-=80%"
          }, 700, function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });
          $(this).html('&raquo;').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');    
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: ">>" image gone some where else .how to close that panel

Comment: no sir please open the panel then check..press ">>" button it open then check

Comment: any suggestion of this question

Comment: @user2484319: really i can't find your problem,i could close and open the panel using the image,it is clearly visible..!!